# Is there a difference between "something" and "anything" in "Nobody can say for sure that something/anything does not exist"?

Tags: meaning, anything-vs-nothing

> 1. Nobody can say for sure that **anything** does not exist. Therefore I can't say for sure that God doesn't exist, just as I can't say for sure that unicorns don't exist.
> 2. Nobody can say for sure that **something** does not exist. Therefore I can't say for sure that God doesn't exist, just as I can't say for sure that unicorns don't exist.

Are the above both correct?

Are they both natural?

Do they mean the same?

Comment: Both are correct.  They are slightly confusing, but it is also a complex idea.  The normal way to say this is: "It is impossible to prove a negative".

Comment: Do you want someone to improve your writing, or do you have a question about the general differences in usage between "anything" and "something"?

Comment: Thank you both. I found 'anything' a bit odd at first, since it is usually used with the negative. But the more I thought about the, the more I liked it, We do say, after all, that anything goes. Here it seems more emphatic than 'something', But as it threw me a bit at first, I thought I might ask to see if the sentence was natural.